# Servlet tag in web.xml Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jax-ws

In Spring, I have confused about servlet tag in web.xml. 
In Spring MVC, why we use servlet-class DispatcherServlet ?
In Spring Jax-ws Webservice, why we use servlet-class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet

So, What is really servlet's function ? And when should we use it ? Is it optional or required ?

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to declare a `<servlet>` tag inside `web.xml` for mapping url.

**References:**
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/